# what does utag.DB mean?

Tags: javascript, console, tealium

I am stumped on figuring out what this means..

```
utag.DB
```

I am seeing it in a web page via the console. And I'm trying to figure out what it means. Any pointers are useful.

Comment: Presumably `utag` is a variable referencing an object that has a property named `DB`. But what it's for is impossible to say out of context.

Comment: maybe some kind of database file?

Comment: How could I extract it's contents with your suggestion? @nnnnnn

Comment: `console.log(utag.DB)` (or even `console.log(utag)`) should show you its contents. If you're already in the console you can just type `utag.DB` and hit enter. (Noting that accessing it directly from the console won't work if it isn't a global variable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utag.db is a Tealium function for debugging. It is similar to console.log(which is non standard). It is enabled via a cookie that's set.

Answer (score 1):

Caught you!!

You are curious about utag means you have implemented or trying to implement **Tealium data layer** in your portal.

Basically utag.db is used to debug tealium functionalities related to utag files. As rightly mentioned by @webanalyticsdood, it should be used instead of non standard console.log

**That's fine but how do I and why should I use it?**

Simple, set utag cookie to true in your developer console using following command

```
document.cookie="utagdb=true";
```

Let's try with following command,

```
utag.data
```

Whatever data you are passing on to tealium will be found inside utag.data. If you can't read your data based on conditional events, it won't be sent to Teamium, better go back and correct your code. Let's try another one.

```
utag.id
```

it will return id you've set for synching with tealium,

You can explore more similar stuff inside utag.js

**PS:** would suggest you to add tealium tag in your question.